# parsing data from JSON

Tags: json, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, ngroute

I am making an AJAX call to a JSON file containing thumbnail images and website urls, I am then listing each out using AngularJS directive ng-repeat to list.  The problem is the thumbnails and website urls are no longer populating my page. I reformatted my JSON file data into an array because I will be adding multiple arrays to my JSON file that will contain different objects to be used on other pages throughout the website.

JSON:

```
{"websites":[
    {
        "thumbnail": "thumbnail1.jpg",
        "website": "http://somewebsite.com"
    },
    {
        "thumbnail": "thumbnail2.jpg",
        "website": "http://somewebsite.com"
    },
    {
        "thumbnail": "thumbnail3.jpg",
        "website": "http://somewebsite.com"
    }
]}
```

Angular:

```
angular.module('myApp')
.constant("dataUrl", "../json/data.json")
.controller("websitesController", function($scope, $http, dataUrl){
    $scope.data ={};

    $http.get(dataUrl)
        .success(function(data){
            $scope.data.projects = data;
        })
        .error(function(error){
            $scope.data.error = error;
        });
});
```

HTML:

```
<ul ng-controller="websitesController">     
                <li ng-repeat="item in data.projects">

                <img ng-src="{{item.thumbnail}}" />

                <div>
                <a ng-href="{{item.website}}" target="_blank"><b>Website</b></a>
                </div>
                </li>
<ul>
```

Comment: You could also log the value, to see what you are actually iterating over, using the json filter `{{ item | json }}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your JSON data has a key called `websites` that is storing an array of websites. You are adding that object with the `websites` key as your `$scope.data.projects`. To access the array of websites, you need to look into that object, i.e., you should assign `$scope.data.projects` to `data.websites`. ***Change your success handler as follows:***

```
.success(function(data){
  $scope.data.projects = data.websites;
})
```

EDIT: data examples --

Your response `data` looks like this:

```
{"websites":[
    {
        "thumbnail": "thumbnail1.jpg",
        "website": "http://somewebsite.com"
    },
    {
        "thumbnail": "thumbnail2.jpg",
        "website": "http://somewebsite.com"
    },
    {
        "thumbnail": "thumbnail3.jpg",
        "website": "http://somewebsite.com"
    }
]}
```

But, you want it to look like this (parsed too) in order to use it in your ng-repeat:

```
[
    {
        "thumbnail": "thumbnail1.jpg",
        "website": "http://somewebsite.com"
    },
    {
        "thumbnail": "thumbnail2.jpg",
        "website": "http://somewebsite.com"
    },
    {
        "thumbnail": "thumbnail3.jpg",
        "website": "http://somewebsite.com"
    }
]
```

Comment: It worked! Thanks. When I add another key to my JSON file I can access the newly created array of objects with the newly created key to that array $scope.data.[something] = data.[key]; ?

Comment: @user3574939 you can add new key-value pairs to your JSON object and access them as you say, except the syntax would be `$scope.data.newKey = data.newKey` or `$scope.data['newKey'] = data['newKey']`. You are mixing the 'dot notation' and 'bracket notation' syntaxes in a way that will throw an error. Please show my answer some upvote love if it helped!

Answer (score 0):

It should be $scope.data.projects=data.websites;